# Code coverage white-/blacklisting in PhpStorm

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

In my project I have a PHPUnit configuration with whitelisting for my code coverage and also some directories excluded. When executing PHPUnit with this configuration and output the code coverage, I only get the whitelisted files in the code coverage.

When I do the same within PhpStorm, it shows code coverage of all files instead of only the whitelisted files.

An example of my PHPUnit configuration:

```
<filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">../../../../Classes/*</directory>

        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">../../../../Tests</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

See the screenshot: it shows that 0% of my files are tested in the Test folder, what is correct because I excluded that folder. But when excluded I don't want to see it as well.

[image: Screenshot of how my coverage looks like in PhpStorm]

Comment: Please clarify the PhpStorm issue with some screenshots.

Comment: Thanks. **P.S.** You should have left the comment mentioning the person (via `@username`) so it receives the notification -- not everybody comes back to check old questions with hard to spot updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot do anything about it -- it's how PhpStorm works right now. If clover coverage report mentions any file then parent folder of such file will have coverage info (`0%` in our case).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16792 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.